# CSS not responding. Caching issue

Tags: caching

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Corey Maller</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I want to make some small changes to my css file but the website is not responding to them. Is there any kind of caching html code I could add to the header?